# Получить SN HDD через WMI в WinXP

Tags: powershell, wmi, windows-xp, windows-server-2003

Можно ли как-то штатными средствами получить серийный номер HDD в WindowsXP? Запрос через win32_physicalmedia и win32_diskdrive не работает на XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, в Windows XP (и в Server 2003) это возможно только на очень малом количестве компьютеров. На моей памяти это был ноутбук не то от Intel, не то от HP, да и то, я подозреваю, класс `Win32_PhysicalMedia` был переписан сторонней программой.
Формально, класс `Win32_PhysicalMedia` имеет свойство `SerialNumber`, но под Windows XP он пуст.
Так что получать серийный номер придётся другим путём. Разумеется, можно создать свой WMI класс, который будет возвращать это значение, но игра не стоит свеч.
Можно создать консольное приложение, выводящее серийник, к нему можно обращаться из powershell, например, так:

```
$getserial = 'path\hddserial.exe'
Start-Process -FilePath $getserial -ArgumentList  'H:\'
```

Comment: В принципе это должно работать только от Win2008/Vista, Win32_PhysicalMedia факически использует класс CIM_PhysicalElement 
 , а у него явно написано что подержка только от Win2008+ https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa387962(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ps: в принципе подойдёт любой нормальный способ получения sn диска на удалённом компе через powershell, можно даже без WMI если такое возможно.

Comment: @vnn198 обновил ответ. Если необходимы варианты, КАК получить серийник для использования в консольном приложении, могу дать пару ссылок на код

Comment: удалённый запуск можно и через GPO из шары сделать, но хотелось обойтись без запуска стороннего ПО, думал может кто знает какой "грязный" трюк

Answer (score 1):

Если получаете номер через командную строку, должна сработать команда:

```
wmic diskdrive get model,name,serialnumber
```

Comment: Под XP он тоже неработает